# Julia set c++ colours

Tags: c++, colors, fractals

I'm currently working on an assignment where I have to produce a Julia set in C++ in sequential, parallel and OpenCL. I have managed to produce an image but the way I have used colours is very ineffective any ideas on how I could improve the colour section of my code at the moment? below is the sequential section of my code any help in improving how I have set the colours would be much appreciated

```
void sequentialJulia(const complex<float>  C, const UINT size = 1000, 
    const UINT MAX_ITERATIONS = 100, const float limit = 1.7f) {
    int start_s = clock();// starts the timer
    // Setup output image
    fipImage outputImage;
    outputImage = fipImage(FIT_BITMAP, size, size, 24);
    UINT bytesPerElement = 3;
    BYTE* outputBuffer = outputImage.accessPixels();
    vector<int> colors{ 100, 140, 180, 220, 225 };// this sets the intsity of the image, if i was to remove 225 the image would be darker 
    //vector<int> colors{9, 19, 29, 39,  49 }; //THIS DOESNT WORK DO NOT UNCOMMENT
    //RGBQUAD color;
    complex<float> Z;

    std::cout << "Processing...\n";
    for (UINT y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        //tracking progress;
        cout << y * 100 / size << "%\r";
        cout.flush();
        for (UINT x = 0; x < size; x++) {

            Z = complex<float>(-limit + 2.0f * limit / size * x, -limit + 2.0f * limit / size * y);
            UINT i;
            for (i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) {
                Z = Z * Z + C;
                if (abs(Z) > 2.0f) break;
            }
            if (i < MAX_ITERATIONS ) { //only changing red byte
                // bytes per element 9 = blue 
                // bytes per element 2 = red 
                // bytes per element 7 = green 
                outputBuffer[( y * size + x) * bytesPerElement + 9] = colors[i % 5]; 

            }


        }

    }

    cout << "Saving image...\n";
    ostringstream name;
    name << "..\\Images\\" << C << " size=" << size << " mIterations=" << MAX_ITERATIONS << " sequential19.png"  ; 
    cout << "saving in: " << name.str().c_str() << "\n";
    outputImage.save(name.str().c_str());

    cout << "...done\n\n";
    int stop_s = clock();
    cout << "time: " << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000 << endl;// stops the timer once code has executed 
}
```

Comment: This question needs some work. For one, it's not a question at all. You are looking for a code review, which is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You would also benefit from https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. After that, try to explain to us the terms we aren't familiar with. Not every C++ dev knows what a Julia set is, myself included.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can 're word it. The code I have produces a Julia set and I can change it to produce one that is either red green or blue. However I am looking to improve it by adding more colours does that make more sense?

Comment: fixed formatting

Comment: Unclear what is going on here. From what I understand colors here are 24-bit RGB, but the way you're setting them simply goes over my head. Are you trying to set colors directly to the bitmap buffer instead of using proper API? You now, like [`setPixelColor()`](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fip/classfipImage.html#a5e71151858ae9a87a21b09b15780ce7f). Also you can pick colors using a system such as HSV to RGB conversion.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, fractal generators from the early 90's (e.g.: [Fractint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractint)) used the iteration-bailout index as an index into a table of 256 Red-Green-Blue colours (This was a common limit, as most displays back then were limited to a colour palette of this size anyway.)

So maybe you could define a table of RGB-colours, then lookup on these up exactly how you perform the `colors[i % 5];` now, except it would output a RGB-triple of `colours[i % TABLE_SIZE].red`, `.green`, `.blue`.  I think it would be best to load your palette in from a separate file.

I've always wondered what a fractal with a 1000-entry colour palette might look like.  Quite pretty I think.

EDIT: IIRC Fractint had a palette editing mode, and could save them to files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent idea of using a look-up table, you can also interpolate between values in the table instead of just doing a modulus operation to pick one. So you could have a 5-color look-up table, but apply it to hundreds or thousands of iterations by linearly interpolating between the 5 colors. For example, if you have a maximum iteration of 256 and your current calculation takes 168 iterations to escape to infinity, and you have a 5-color look-up table, you could do this to get a color:

```
float lookupVal =  static_cast<float>((colors.size - 1) * i) / MAX_ITERATIONS;
int   lookupIndex  = static_cast<int>(floor(lookupValue));
float fraction  =  lookupVal - floor(lookupVal);
float colorF =  static_cast<float>(colors [ lookupIndex ]) + fraction * static_cast<float>(colors [ lookupIndex + 1 ] - colors [ lookupIndex ]);
uint8_t color = static_cast<uint8_t>(colorF);
```

If  your look-up table had RGB values instead of just grayscale, you would need to calculate `colorF` and `color` for each color channel (red, green, and blue).